# Permissions required for these TFS (on premise) REST urls?

Tags: rest, tfs

I am trying to automate some jobs that require information about agent pools and agents and while the job script works just fine for regular users of my TFS collection it fails miserably for a service account.

My job script tries to access urls

```
http://<instance>/<collection>/_apis/distributedtask/pools
http://<instance>/<collection>/_apis/distributedtask/pools/<pool>/agents
```

Initially my service account got a response like

```
TF400813: The user &#39;<service account>&#39; is not authorized to access this resource
```

The service account was previously not member of any TFS related AD group but after creating a new group and adding it to 'Project Collection Valid Users' the call does not fail but the response does not include any pool information still.

If I modify the service account interactive logins the GUI for agents in the agent pool shows no information but the hint

```
no agents are registered or you do not have permission to view the agents
```

suggests that permission is missing.

I have tried to add the service account to various groups in TFS like Project Collection Administrators, Project Collection Build Administrators, etc. all to no avail.

So in short, what permissions does a service account need to retrieve information from the urls mentioned in the start?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue, it does not work even change the regular users as the service account.

So, as a workaround for now you can call the REST API using the regular users or PAT in your script.

Below PowerShell script works for me:

```
$user = "Domain\username"
$token = "password"

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "http://SERVER:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/1/agents/5"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "result = $($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Comment: Yes, that would work but for company policy reasons it is not feasible for me.

Comment: @MichaelWraa-Hansen What about the PAT? You can create secret variables for the user and password or PAT, then use the variables in your script.

Comment: I suppose I could use it as a temporary solution but with no prospect of getting a proper solution I think it will not do no matter if the password is kept in one place or another. The requirement to change user passwords often would also make it a nuisance.
PS: I am using TFS 17 update 2 if that matters.